# What is the preferred way to store a ~1000 element array of Strings in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, redis

In my Rails app, I will have an array with 1000 animal names. So, basically Strings. These names will never have any more data associated with them. I think making an animals table for them is overkill, because I use the Array only to sample an animal.

At the same time, I have REDIS in my project, and was thinking of just doing the following:

`redis.set("animals", ["large", "array", "of", "animals", ...].to_json)`

I'm not sure if that is problematic though and if I should worry that I'm storing a 1000 element array. I know there are HUGE data sets out there, but is 1000 anything worth worrying about?

Perhaps I should store them in a `.txt` file? One animal per line, so I would just use `lines = File.foreach("animals"); lines.sample`?

What is the best way to tackle this?

Comment: Have you checked the memory usage of the array when stored in redis?  By the way, why do you think it is problematic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1000 rows is plenty for their own model/table. Databases have been used, abused, and refined for decades. Overkill is not really a concern unless you have a very good reason to suspect performance issues, which is unlikely, and even then, premature optimization is the root of all evil as they say. Keep you code clean and easily expandable. E.g., in `animal.rb`:

```
# return a random animal
def self.sample
  offset(rand(count)).first
end
```

Whenever you need a sample (presumably in a controller) it's as simple as `Animal.sample`. And you might decide later that you want additional associations with those animals.